# What is this view called? IOS

Tags: ios

I've seen this all over IOS apps and I'm trying to add it to my own. I know it won't be hard, but I need someone to point me in the direction of some apple documentation by telling me what developers refer to it as.

Talking about the options that slide up from the bottom

[image]

Comment: It is a UIActionSheet

Comment: It's UIActionSheet. You can use it like above or you can use it with UIPicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As rmaddy pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640618/what-is-this-view-called-ios#comment23932507_16640618), this is called a `UIActionSheet`, and it used to present the user with a set of alternatives to proceed with a given task.

More information:

[Simple Menus and Messages with UIActionSheet - iOS developer tips](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/simple-menus-and-messages-with-uiactionsheet.html)

[UIActionSheet Class Reference - developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)